# Calculating the area of a shapefile

Tags: gis, openmap, anylogic

I'm using AnyLogic's new GIS capabilities, which in turn uses the OpenMap API. I want to figure out the area of each shapefile I'm using, each of which is represented by an AnyLogic `ShapeGISMap.Layer` that uses an OpenMap `AreaShapeLayer` (both of which I can play with). How do I calculate the area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one way I can think of: Plot the content of your shapefile using a polyline (or some other AL markup element) and calculate its area using known syntax.
Otherwise, resort to some geo-processing tool such as ArcGIS :-(